# Get number of rows of the sum of two columns and group these rows

Tags: sql, codeigniter, count

Sorry if the title is a little weird... but basically want I want to do is... I'll do an example first then I'll post the code I have

**TableA** has these columns

- d-id (INT)
- content (TEXT)

**TableB** has these columns

- d-id (INT)
- dif_content (TEXT)

and there's a **TableC** that has the column `d-id`.

Now I'm trying to  get the number of rows from `content` and `dif_content` and `SUM` these two columns while grouping them based on the `d-id`

**TableC** has `main_content` where I wanted the number of `content` and `dif_content` like so:

- a row(1)
- another row(5)
- another row again(3)

The number in the rows is how many rows of `content` and `dif_content` I have for that row.

This is the code I have right now

```
    $query = $this->db->query(
            'SELECT TableA.d-id , TableB.d-id , count(TableA.content) as num_content , count(TableB.dif_content) AS num_dif_content 
             FROM TableA , TableB
             WHERE TableA.d-id = TableB.d-id
             SUM(num_content + num_dif_content) as content_total'
```

and just to for more detail, I'm using Codeigniter, so if you got a way to do this using Active Record, that would be nice.

This is the most complex query I have ever done. (for the few years that I've been programming)

I apologize if you can't understand what I'm trying to do, just comment if you need to know more, and I'll happily edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm, maybe I do not understant your question clearly. If I am right, this can be the query you need:

```
SELECT 
    *, count_t1 + count_t2 as count_all
FROM
    (SELECT d_id, COUNT(content) as count_t1 FROM TableA GROUP BY d_id) t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT d_id, COUNT(dif_content) as count_t2 FROM TableB GROUP BY d_id) t2
    ON t1.d_id = t2.d_id;
```

You can preview using this [sqlfiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a97ec/4/0)